# Fullscreen Windows with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

How can one get a frame in Tkinter to display in fullscreen mode?

I'm working on a program that will have two windows. The main window will house the settings options, and the 2nd window will open at a specific time and should be displayed in fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 6):

This worked pretty well for me:

```
>>> import Tkinter
>>> root = Tkinter.Tk()
>>> root.overrideredirect(True)
>>> root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(),
                                       root.winfo_screenheight()))
```

I'm using OS X -- the title bar and top-level menu bar remained, but the window covered the dock. Let me know if you need more.